# Chamar variável em outro main

Tags: java

Eu já não sei mais o que fazer, preciso de ajuda. Eu quero imprimir todos os clientes cadastros e salvos em `public static void clientes()`, mas para a impressão eu criei um `public static void imp()`, e quando eu tento fazer a chamada lá, não dá, aparece na variável `clientes`:

> "cannot find symbol".

PF, me ajudem, eu preciso entregar isso até amanhã.

```
public static void cliente() {
    CadastroCliente cc = new CadastroCliente(); 
    
    cc.nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o nome do cliente: ");
    cc.CPF = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o CPF do cliente: "); 
    
    List<CadastroCliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
    clientes.add(cc);

}

public static void imp() {
    for (int i = 0; i < clientes.size(); i++) {
        CadastroCliente obj = clientes.get(i);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, clientes.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa tirar o `List<CadastroCliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();` de dentro do método `cliente()`, pois da forma que está escrito, a variável `clientes` está com visibilidade local, ou seja, apenas dentro do método. Declare fora do método para que a variável possua visibilidade em toda a classe.
**Segue um exemplo funcional:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class variavel_visivel {
    static List<CadastroCliente> clientes;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        clientes = new ArrayList<>();
        cliente();
        cliente();
        imp();
    }
    
    public static void cliente() {
        CadastroCliente cc = new CadastroCliente(); 
        cc.nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o nome do cliente: ");
        cc.CPF = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o CPF do cliente: "); 
        
        clientes.add(cc);

    }

    public static void imp() {
        for (int i = 0; i < clientes.size(); i++) {
            CadastroCliente obj = clientes.get(i);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nome: " + obj.nome +", CPF: "+obj.CPF);
        }
    }
}
```